# Convert a specific column to Dateobjects

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, spreadsheets

I have searched around but haven't found an answer to the following problem.

I have a spreadsheet with a large number of rows and 4 columns.

Column 3 contains dates not in a right format. So I want to convert column 3 to date objects and keep everything else.

```
data1 = {#[[1]],#[[2]],DateObject[#[[3]]],#[[4]]} & /@ Rest@data;
```

Here *data* is my imported data from the sheet.

My question: Assume that my sheet contains say 100 columns with Dates in column 37th.

How can I achieve the same thing as above?

Comment: `MapAt[DateObject, yourData, {All, 37}]`

Comment: @MarcoB Thank so much. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll convert my comment to an answer, just so that the question has one. You can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) to apply a function at a specific location in a nested list:

```
MapAt[DateObject, yourData, {All, 37}]
```

This will apply the `DateObject` function to the 37th column of your data set.